# Experimentally calculating of ionisation energy of Hydrogen atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, atomic-physics, spectroscopy, hydrogen

I am very curious to know that how we can experimentally find the ionisation energy of Hydrogen atom upto the maximum precision possible ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome Lokesh.  It isn't clear whether you are asking how the world's current best value for the hydrogen ionization energy is determined, or whether you have made some hydrogen spectrum measurements yourself and want to know how to use them to calculate the hydrogen atom ionization energy.